# barChartData backgroundColor and borderColor properties missing in ng2-charts bar panel

Tags: angular, dashboard, ng2-charts

**backgroundColor** and **borderColor** properties are missing for barchartdata in [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#BarChart) bar panel generated through a model barchartmodel.mode.ts file via a  service call. However for the  initialised values of barChartData in the component file as below all the properties are generated correctly.

**bar.component.ts**

```
export class BarComponent implements OnInit {
public barChartData: ChartDataSets[];
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
this.barChartData= [
{
data: [1000], 
label: 'Alpha',
},
{
data: [2000], 
label: 'Bravo',
}
]; 
}
```

**####console.log output for above data with static declaration**

```
0:
backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.6)"
borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)"
data: [1000, _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]
hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.8)"
hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)"
label: "Alpha"
_meta: {1: {…}}
__proto__: Object
1:
backgroundColor: "rgba(54,162,235,0.6)"
borderColor: "rgba(54,162,235,1)"
data: [2000, _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]
hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(54,162,235,0.8)"
hoverBorderColor: "rgba(54,162,235,1)"
label: "Bravo"
_meta: {1: {…}}
__proto__: Object
```

**###business service call to populate barChartData from backend**

```
ngOnInit() {

myserviceCall.subscribe(
(subscribedData:any)=>{
subscribedData.map(
(bar: Barchartmodel) => {
new Barchartmodel().deserialize(bar); 
console.info('JSON.stringify(bar)) =',JSON.stringify(bar));
this.barChartData.push({
data:bar["data"],
label:bar["label"]
});
console.log("this.barChartData="+this.barChartData);
}); 
} 
);
}
```

**####console.log output for service loaded data with missing backgroundColor property**

```
2:
data: [8, _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]
label: "Abdulla44517616"
_meta: {1: {…}}
__proto__: Object
3:
data: [74, _chartjs: {…}, push: ƒ, pop: ƒ, shift: ƒ, splice: ƒ, …]
label: "VivekSaxena82"
_meta: {1: {…}}
__proto__: Object
```

**####Barchartmodel.ts implementing the ChartDataSets**

```
import { ChartType, ChartDataSets, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { Deserializable } from './deserializable';
export class Barchartmodel implements ChartDataSets,Deserializable{
deserialize(input: any): this {
Object.assign(this, input);
 return this;
}
data: [];
label: 'labelName'
}
```

Why is the backgroundColor property missing in the second case? Is there a problem with the BarchartModel or the service logic of pushing barChartModel into barChartData?

**Reference Image output** [image: here]